# Botões com Action de HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, html, html5, twitter-bootstrap, node.js

O Request do Click do Botão está recebendo: { 'QTD1LED, ON': '' }, porém gostaria de receber somente {QTD1LED, ON}. Aonde tenho é a alteração no meu código?

```
var http = require("http").createServer(servidor);
var express = require('express');
var io = require("socket.io").listen(http);
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");
var querystring = require('querystring');
var fs = require('fs');

var contentTypes = {
    js: 'text/javascript',
    css: 'text/css',
    json: 'application/json',
    png: 'image/png',
    jpg: 'image/png',
    wav: 'audio/wav'
};

function processPost(request, response, callback) {
    // Código boilerplate pra receber a querystring pedido HTTP,
    // convertê-la e formatá-la em uma coleção de pares chave-valor

    var queryData = "";
    if(typeof callback !== 'function') return null;

    request.on('data', function(data) {
        queryData += data;
    });

    request.on('end', function() {
        request.post = querystring.parse(queryData);
        callback();
    });
}

function servidor(req, res) {
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    var filePath = '.' + req.url;

    if(req.method == 'POST') {
        // Se o método do pedido for HTTP POST, processa a querystring

        processPost(req, res, function() {
            // Imprime a querystring convertida em chaves-valores
            console.log(req.post);

            // O request.post está disponível para ser usado aqui

            // Retorna a página para o cliente com o cód. HTTP 200 (OK)
            res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.end();
        });
    }
    else if (filePath == './' || filePath == './index.html') filePath = './index.html';
    else contentType = contentTypes[req.url.split('.').pop()];
    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        if (error) {
            if (error.code == 'ENOENT') {
                fs.readFile('./404.html', function(error, content) {
                    res.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                    });
                    res.end(content, 'utf-8');
                });
            } else {
                res.writeHead(500);
                res.end('Ooops... houve um erro: ' + error.code + ' ..\n');
                res.end();
            }
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': contentType
            });
            res.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });
}


app.get('/teste', function(req, res) {
    res.charset = 'UTF-8'
    res.send(recebido);
});


http.listen(5000, "192.168.0.108", function() {
    var host = http.address().address;
    var port = http.address().port;
    console.log('Exemplo na URL http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SmartHouse</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="/css/plugins/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> -->
    <script src="/font-awesome/font.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script> <!-- chamamos o socket.io que por padrão o socket.io cria a rota http sem precisarmos interferir -->

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Sistema Smart House - Automação Residencial</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Top Menu Items -->

            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="sala.html"><i class="fa fa-television"></i> Sala</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="cozinha.html"><i class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></i> Cozinha</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><i class="fa fa-bed"></i> Quartos <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="quarto1.html"> Quarto 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="quarto2.html"> Quarto 2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> Alarme</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <!-- Page Heading -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">
                            Quarto 1 <small>Geral</small>
                        </h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li class="active">
                                <i class="fa fa-bed"></i> Quarto 1
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h1><center>Quarto 1 - Lampada</center></h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <a onclick="enviarComandoON()" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" id="QTD1LED, ON">ON</a>
                                    <a onclick="enviarComandoOFF()" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" id="QTD1LED, OFF">OFF</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->

        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
    <script src="/js/plugins/morris/raphael.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/plugins/morris/morris-data.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('QTD1LED, ON').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        // Obtém os valores dos elementos #qrt e #led
        var status = document.getElementById('QTD1LED, ON').id;

        // Monta querystring para o POST com os valores dos elementos
        var params = status;

        // Monta a requisição POST
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("POST", true);

        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            // Chama uma função quando o status do pedido for alterado
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                // Se o status for HTTP 200 (ok) e readyState==4 (DONE)
                alert('O servidor recebeu: ' + params);
            }
        }

        // Envia a requisição
        http.send(params);
    });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: começa estudando sobre o [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), que mais popularmente é chamado de AJAX. Se você quer algo bem facil usa jQuery que facilita essa, e outras, partes.

Answer (score 1):

Para conseguir isso, é interessante enviar os dados via AJAX para o servidor em nodejs. Provavelmente você vai acabar optando por algum framework, mas a título de exercício, vale a pena ver como se faz na mão.

Para ficar muito simples, esse servidor diferencia os pedidos entre POST e GET (sem verificar o caminho da requisição). Se for POST, ele imprime no console os dados, se for GET ele retorna o index.html:

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var fs = require('fs');


function processPost(request, response, callback) {
    // Código boilerplate pra receber a querystring pedido HTTP,
    // convertê-la e formatá-la em uma coleção de pares chave-valor

    var queryData = "";
    if(typeof callback !== 'function') return null;

    request.on('data', function(data) {
        queryData += data;
    });

    request.on('end', function() {
        request.post = querystring.parse(queryData);
        callback();
    });
}

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    // Função que receberá os pedidos HTTP na porta especificado em
    // listen() logo abaixo

    if(request.method == 'POST') {
        // Se o método do pedido for HTTP POST, processa a querystring

        processPost(request, response, function() {
            // Imprime a querystring convertida em chaves-valores
            console.log(request.post);

            // O request.post está disponível para ser usado aqui

            // Retorna a página para o cliente com o cód. HTTP 200 (OK)
            response.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            response.end();
        });
    } else {
        // Se o método não for POST, assume que é GET e que está
        // requisitando o index.html

        fs.readFile('./index.html', function(error, content) {
            if (error) {
                // Se houve um erro ao carregar o arquivo,
                // retorna HTTP 500

                response.writeHead(500);
                response.end('Erro interno do servidor');
            }
            else {
                // Se não houve erro retorna o conteúdo do index.html
                response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                response.end(content, 'utf-8');
            }
        });
    }

}).listen(8000);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
```

O index.html é bem simples também, apenas monta o pedido e envia utilizando [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
    <div>
        Quarto: <input type="number" name="qrt" id="qrt" value="1">
    </div>
    <div>
        LED:
        <select name="led" id="led">
            <option value="ON">ON</option>
            <option value="OFF">OFF</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="submit">
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // Obtém os valores dos elementos #qrt e #led
    var qrt = document.getElementById('qrt').value;
    var led = document.getElementById('led').value;

    // Monta querystring para o POST com os valores dos elementos
    var params = 'valor={QRT' + qrt + 'LED, ' + led + '}';

    // Monta a requisição POST
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", '', true);

    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // Chama uma função quando o status do pedido for alterado
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            // Se o status for HTTP 200 (ok) e readyState==4 (DONE)
            alert('O servidor recebeu: ' + params);
        }
    }

    // Envia a requisição
    http.send(params);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Leia a referência para o XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (lá tem a descrição e explicação das funções, dos códigos readyState, além de exemplos e links para artigos sobre isso).

Esses dois arquivos compõem um exemplo mínimo testável do que você deseja fazer. Se tiver alguma dificuldade para rodar eles, eu posso incluir instruções aqui na resposta.

Comment: muito obrigado pelo código! Consegue colocar alguns comentários para eu entender melhor? Não consegui tempo para testar, mas pelo visto irá funcionar!

Comment: Eu mudei o código e usei com o bootstrap, porém, além de não carregar o bootstrap quando acesso http://127.0.0.1:8000, o botão "OFF" não funciona, além da variavel qrt não receber o value.

Consegue dar uma olhada no código? (Editei na primeira pergunta)

Comment: Depende da sua estrutura de arquivos, veja nas ferramentas do desenvolvedor se tá dando algum erro. Talvez você tenha mais sorte usando CDNs para carregar os scripts.

Comment: Primeiramente você tem dois elementos com o mesmo id (o id deve ser único em um documento). Além disso, o meu código não vai funcionar com <button>s pois foi escrito para pegar as informações a partir de um <select>. Outro problema é que os botões tipicamente não guardam estado (selecionado e não-selecionado). Frameworks como bootstrap dão um jeito nisso modificando um `<input type=radio>` para se parecer com botão http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons

Comment: comentei o código para você entender melhor

Comment: eu testei, porém o servidor está recebendo { 'QTD1LED, ON': '' }

Como faço para alterar para somente {QTD1LED,ON}?